# How to fix bootstrap modal in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

When I click on Add Blogger, instead of opening modal, page just gets redirected to home page. How can I fix the issue?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addblogger">Add Blogger</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="addblogger">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Blogger</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the id of the modal as the href of the a element otherwise the "#" will cause the redirect.

```
<a href="#addblogger" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">
  Add Blogger
</a>
```

You can do it the way you have it (using the data-target attribute), but you will need a javascript:void(0) on the href - to avoid the redirection. I wouldn't do this though

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="addblogger">
  Add Blogger
</a>
```

**If I was going to use a data-target and use the btn classes - I would use a button element.**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="addblogger">
  Add Blogger
</button>
```